# Elsarticle with AMA bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, elsarticle

For an `elsarticle` template, how to generate AMA citations? I added the `ama.bst` bibliography style to the paper working directory. Using MikTeX2.9:

The paper:

```
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\title{ \textbf{All the Cats}}
\section*{Citing cats author}

All the cats in the world as eloquently explained in reference \cite{Cat19}. 
This should have printed as [1]!\\

In References, the citation should appear as: \textbf{Catty CT, Katin KK, 
and Kitty MM. An amazing account of cats around the world.}\textit{ J. Cats. 
Life} \textbf{2019; 19:290-299.}

\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{ama} 
\bibliography{catsbib}

\end{document}
```

catsbib.bib

```
@article{Cat19,
  author = "Catty, CT and Katin, KK and Kitty, MM",
   title = "An amazing Account of cats around the world",
    year = "2019",
 journal = "J {C}ats {L}ife",
  volume = "19",
  number = "9",
   pages = "290--299"
  }
```

When compiling with pdfLatex+MakeIndex+Bibtex, latex hangs with:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The desired output is shown below:

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!